# installing msttcorefonts on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm generating PDF's with something called [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/), it seems [it requires](http://www.princexml.com/doc/6.0/fonts/) a package called: msttcorefonts

I have been unable to use aptitude to get it and I recived this as an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package msttcorefonts is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package msttcorefonts has no installation candidate
```

How can I get this package installed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update for year 2015:

Add this to (or uncomment in) /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
```

Then run this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

Comment: archive.ubuntu.com will get you the nearest mirror (instead of us.archive.ubuntu.com which will get you only the nearest mirror in the US.)

Comment: Also, there's now trusty-security repos as well.  I've edited the answer to reflect these.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to have changed in karmic. There is no package `msttcorefonts` anymore.

Use the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` from the Multiverse repository instead.

How to enable the Mutliverse repository see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

Then install with:

```
   sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Technically speaking the package doesn't contain the fonts, but rather automatically downloads and installs them - hence the name change.

Comment: great! funny thing is that `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` wasn’t in the multiverse repo either, but running the old command did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Enabling the multiverse (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) and then installing with msttcorefonts worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

ttf-mscorefonts-installer isn't in the multiverse either

Answer (score 1):

http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/

Specifically, look under the package names listed on that page itself, not on the download links.